# MVC Right separation for functional component

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, view

I am building a Web application that allow people to subscribe to certain classes which are divided by semesters.

In one of my interface I have a list of all activities that act as a summary in the backend interface. I was looking to group them by semester and browse through a sequential navigation.

My problem is, where should I put my code since I want it to be easy to maintain and I want to respect the right MVC structure.

Here are my Ideas:

1. Get the param value in the controller, get the previous and next semester through an
    action helper, send the data to the view and then display it

   or
2. Get the param value in the controller, sent it to the view, let the view (through a
    view helper) find the previous and next semester and then display it

I have a class that is able to find the semesters through calculation (so it's not in my models)

Comment: Try to use the term "model" too in your arguments.

Comment: The problem doesn't lie in my models, it a separation of concerns between the controller and the view.

Comment: just making sure you're using them and not purely controllers :) I'd go with 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option. Your question is unclear to me, but your first option sounds the closest to what I would do.